Simulator won't show dropdown with FormBuilderDropdown
VS Code is showing the FormBuilderDropdown with a red highlight, but no error.  And when I run it on the ios simulator, it freezes the simulator but doesn't crash it.  Here's a screenshot of the code to show the red highlight

Does anyone know how to fix it?
